# TEXTJOIN Formula with IF Condiion not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using TEXTJOIN function in Google Sheets with If condition. When i apply below formula it is working fine where `=1`

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(B2:N2=1,$B$1:$N$1 & "?","")))
```

But when i apply this with `=0` it incluides all the empty cell.

```
 =ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(B2:N2=0,$B$1:$N$1 & "?","")))
```

[link sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Laq0FeFge0q59yAiEGBA9-X8-DQ9duEmxdbxjwUi35A/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the formula to

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF( ISNUMBER(B2:N2)*(B2:N2=0),$B$1:$N$1 & "?","")))
```

and see if that works?